# Generate sequence from a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sequence

Client have one requirement that, content text should start with a new sequence number for each separate content. For Content JSON, Consider following sample JSON. I will get this JSON in front-end as a response from backend. I'm iterating that JSON recursively, So now I want to create its sequence number while iterating over it. What's the easy way to do that?

```
var myobj = {
"name": "sample",                     //1
"def": [                              //2
      {
        "setId": 1,                    //2.1.1
         "setDef": [                   //2.1.2
            {        
                "type": "STRING",      //2.1.2.1.1
                "name": "ABC"          //2.1.2.1.2
            },
            {
                "type": "STRING",      //2.1.2.2.1
                 "name": "XYZ"          //2.1.2.1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "setId": 2,                 //2.2.1
        "setDef": [                 //2.2.2
            {
                "type": "STRING",   //2.2.2.1.1
                "name": "abc"       //2.2.2.1.2
            },
            {
                "type": "STRING",   //2.2.2.2.1
                "name": "xyz"       //2.2.2.1.1
            }
        ]
    }
],
"property": {         //3
    {
        "color": "red" //3.1.1
    },
    {
        "run": true    //3.2.1
    },
    {
        "width": [120, 330, 332]   //3.3.1
    }
},
listing: true  //4
```

};

Here is my code:

```
function displayContent(obj) {
    jQuery.each(obj, function(key, val) {
         recursiveIterObj(key, val, obj); 
    });
}
function recursiveIterObj(key, val, obj) {
        if(!isplain(val)){
            setContentData(key, curr_seq, last_seq, "");
            $.each(val, function(k,v){
                recursiveIterObj(k, v, val);
            });
        }else{
            setContentData(key, curr_seq, last_seq, val);
        }
}

function isplain(data) {
    return (typeof data === 'string' || typeof data === 'number')?
       true:false;
}
function setContentData(key, curr_seq, last_seq, val){
            $(".heading").text(key);
            $(".sequence").txt(curr_seq); // if this is 2.1.2 or 4
            $(".sequence_last").txt(last_seq); // then, this should be 2.1.1 or 3
            $(".txt_content").text(val);
}
$(function(){
 displayContent(obj);
})
```

**NOTE** - Above JSON is a random json from internet.

Comment: JSON !== JavaScript Object

Comment: @yoshi no that was for trex

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, yo can check it [here](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 1):

Properties order in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript.Only in case of array,you will see sequence while iterating in JavaScript.

Since ECMAScript 2015, using the `Map` object could be an alternative. A Map share some similarities with an Object and guarantee the keys order.